# Null pointer error when using conj with an array in a loop

Tags: arrays, loops, clojure, variable-assignment

Working on the problems on Project Euler to try to learn Clojure. I'm on problem 7.

I'm getting a nullpointer and I can't work out what on earth I've done wrong.

```
;;By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can
;;see that the 6th prime is 13.
;;
;;What is the 10 001st prime number?

(defn isPrime [x]
    (if-not (> x 2) false (loop [i 2]
            (if (= i x)
                true
                (if (= (mod x i) 0) false (recur (inc i)) )
            )
        )
    )
)


(loop [ x [2]
        y 3   ]
    (if (= (count x) 6)
        (println (last x))
        ( if (isPrime y) ((let [x (conj x y)]) (println (str (last x)))) )
    )
    (if-not (= (count x) 10001) (recur x (inc y)) )
)
```

The error is with the `( if (isPrime y) ((let [x (conj x y)]) (println (str (last x)))) )`, according to java.

Here's the traceback..

```
gcoles@gcoles-pc:~/euler$ clj 7.clj 
2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at user$eval2.invoke(7.clj:21)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6511)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6952)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:6912)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:283)
    at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:343)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:427)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:415)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
```

The nullpointer actually doesn't occur until the second time around the loop (Seen by putting a `print` after that `let`), so this confuses me a bit..

Anyone got any ideas on this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `let` is of the following form:

```
(let [binding values]
  (body))
```

This will return the result of evaluating `body`. In the code above, your `let` form looks like this:

```
(let [x (conj x y)])
```

Notice how there's no body. Because of this, the `let` form returns `nil`. Since it's `nil`, the code you're really envoking looks like this:

```
(nil (println (str (last x))))
```

Because of this, you're effectively trying calling `nil` as a function. This causes your null pointer exception. If, for example, you make your code:

```
(let [x (conj x y)] (println (str (last x))))
```

It will print out the last value of `x`. However, it's worth noting that this new `x` (the result of `(conj x y)`) is scoped only to the `let` statement. If you actually want to use it elsewhere, you'll have to, for example, `recur` with it.

Comment: Ahh, of course, I didn't think of that.. Is there a way of modifying `x` within the loop though, instead of using `recur` (since `recur` has to be at the end)?

Comment: Sure. I think one option is actually moving _everything_ into the body of a `let` statement. So, `(loop [x [2], y 3] (let [new-x (if (isPrime y) (conj x y) x)] ... (recur new-x (inc y))))`, that way you can refer to the new x value (the updated list of primes) inside the rest of the loop logic.

Comment: Aha, great idea. I'll look into it tomorrow. Thanks :3